# Close menu with click off menu itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm not the best when it comes to JavaScript, and stuck with finding a solution.  I have seen similar questions asked here, but when I try to implement it in my case it either breaks the menu or just makes no difference.

I'm trying to get a menu (which opens on a click), to close not only with a repeated click on parent menu tab, but with a click outside the menu, i.e., anywhere.

My code is:

```
var toggleUpdatesPulldown = function(event, element, user_id) {
    if( element.className=='updates_pulldown' ) {
        element.className= 'updates_pulldown_active';
        showNotifications();
    } else {
        element.className='updates_pulldown';
    }
}
```

This snippet is in the middle of a lot more JavaScript and this is the default working version. The click from user changes the class name of the menu container which determines if it's displayed or not. From another post on here, I tried implementing the following to no avail to try and allow the click off to alter the class name as well:

```
var toggleUpdatesPulldown = function(event, element, user_id) {
    if( element.className=='updates_pulldown' ) {
        element.className= 'updates_pulldown_active';
        showNotifications();
    } else {
        element.className='updates_pulldown';
    }
    
    ev.stopPropagation();
    
    $(document).one('click', function() {
        element.className='updates_pulldown';
    });
}
```

Any advice on tackling this?  I'd like to learn more JavaScript as I seem to be working with it more and more.

Comment: Welcome! Please make a functioning demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice it... you have $(document).one('click'... that should be on, not one.

Comment: If you were actually looking to use jQuery, you could use `$.mouseleave()` to handle the opening/closing.

Comment: @BobDavies - There is a [`$.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) that fires only once per element.

Comment: Phil, here's a [menu demo](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QtaMG/) I was putting together that was meant to be simply a demonstration (so it's not necessarily going to handle multiple levels and isn't perfect by any means). You can `$.bind()` and `$.unbind()` handlers on menu expand/contract as well, or use `$.on()` or `$.one()` to trap *other* clicks, but I like the elegance of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not use JQuery if possible - it's just I took it from a previous solution one here - the site is using MooTools. Is there a plain Javascript method to doing this guys?

Comment: If you can make a http://jsfiddle.net of what you've got so far, that would be really useful. `:)` Also, are you worried about supporting legacy browsers which don't have [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector)?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are still looking for a solution. Here's a working demo of this http://jsfiddle.net/sU9ZJ/6/

```
(function(win, doc) {
  var lis = $('#menu>ul>li>a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this);
    var li = $(this).parent();
    function close(dev) {
      if (!(dev && li.has(dev.target)[0])) {
        li.addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
        doc.off('click', close);
        a.trigger('close');
      }
    }
    function open(dev) {
      li.addClass('active');
      doc.on('click', close);
      a.trigger('open');
    }
    if (li.hasClass('active')) {  close() } 
    else {  open(); }        
  })      
})(this, $(document))
```

I have also added a couple of events that you can use when it opens or closes

```
$('#menu>ul>li>a').on('open', function(e) { 
     console.log('menu open', this) 
}).on('close', function(e) { 
      console.log('menu closed', this) 
})
```

Sorry, this depends on jQuery. too lazy to write a native version :). Also this is not tested in IE, but shouldn't be too hard to make it work on those if it doesn't.